# Android studio error i can't build any app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm from a country that is blocked from google android developers so I download it through `en.uptodown.com`. I have installed and everything but still I can't build any app.

I tried to use offline mode but nothing helped me to fix this error and when I use it without offline mode I wait a lot and I don't get anything, [screenshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1TI3.png)

Please keep it in mind I can't use SDK manager because I'm from blocked countries.
If anyone can help me how to use the Android Studio offline and which SDK files that I need to use android studio offline because I start to think I have to use eclipse but it's old

Comment: Just a guess - you can try using some VPN service to temporarily obtain an ip from another country

Comment: it doesn't  work with sdk manger I don't know why but i use pisphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the this [link](http://www.april1985.com/android-sdk-offline/) to download what ever you need. It contain all the `build-tools` and `platform tools`.

Comment: Try this and let me know the results

Comment: it's blocked too i'm sorry my problem it's in SDK but not exactly i can't build any app because of gradle i can't sync files with it

Comment: after getting backups of your `codes` do a clean reinstall. try it and let me know you r results, but before uninstalling be sure to take a copy of the `sdk` or else you will have to download it again

Comment: i did all that and i downloaded gradle files. zip 2.14 and reinstall but the same problem in gradle error sync and android repository breaked

Comment: when your are creating a project, what is the minimum `sdk`you choose, try to choose the newest `sdk`

Answer (score -1):

You should change your country in your control panel
Windows 10 : Settings -> Time & Language -> Region and Language
I hope this helps, haven't tried it yet.